# Windows 8 must be restarted after switching wireless networks

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8

When switching to a different wireless network, I get an APIPA address after connecting. I have tried ipconfig /release / ipconfig /renew without success. Only after restarting the system am I able to get an address from DHCP. After that, everything works normally, even through multiple restarts. Only when I move to another network, even one I was connected to before, the problem starts again.

I have the following barebones laptop: http://www.asipartner.com/Solutions/Mobile/BTONotebookMatrix/tabid/114/~/Solutions/Mobile/MobileCenter/ProductFullDetails/tabid/466/sku/87776/Default.aspx

The wireless card is a Qualcomm Atheros AR9285. The driver currently in use is the native Windows 8 driver 3.0.0.130. When I tried to update it with the one from the manufacturer's website, Windows said the most current driver was already in use.

The OS is Windows 8 Pro x64. Clean install. Other applications are installed which some kind of virtual network interface:

- SonicWall Global VPN Client 4.7.3.0403
- VirtualBox 4.2.4r81584 (No Virtual Interfaces Currently Installed)

Answer (score 0):

I am 99% certain that this is a driver issue. The fact that it connects once rules out any apps, which only leaves the drivers and i the OS (and it doesn't happen to me, so its not the OS), try this:

- Download latest driver from website
- Go to the Win + X menu and open device manager
- Right click on the driver and choose update driver software
- Choose to browse your PC and locate the driver

This will force it to install the new driver for the NIC.